# Setting up dynamic ActionBar Title using NuxtJS (VueJS) and <keep-alive/> mutation problem

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

Normally, with **VueCLI3**, I used to set dynamic titles for **ActionBar** (eg. `Vuetify`) with `vue-router meta` properties (Kind-of static, since they are set up in the `router.js` file)

Example:

```js
// router.js

const routes = [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'Home',
      component: Home,
      meta : {
        title : 'Welcome Home',
      }
    },
]
```

```js
// in App.vue 
<template>
  <v-app>
    <ActionBar :title="$route.meta.title"></ActionBar>
    <router-view></router-view> 
  </v-app>
</template>
```

With **Nuxt.JS**, I could not have found anyways to set `route-meta`, so I used **`Vuex.store`** `getter` and `mutations` to set titles in the store and fetch in the **main layout**.

Example:

```js
// in mainLayout.vue
<template>
  <v-app dark> 
    <v-app-bar app color="primary" dark>
      <v-toolbar-title v-text="actionTitle" />
    </v-app-bar>

    <v-main>
      <v-container>
        <nuxt keep-alive />
      </v-container>
    </v-main>

  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters([
      'actionTitle'
    ])
  },
}
```

```js
// in some routed page, eg: index.vue
export default {
  created() {
    this.$store.commit('setActionTitle', 'Medical Service BD')
  },
}
```

Problem happens when I use **`<nuxt keep-alive />`** or use **cached** components. This caching, does not commit those mutations so the action bar title remains static of last title.

Which method should be the appropriate one for dynamic title setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found from reddit, is by using `activated` method. Example:

```js
export default {
  activated() {
    this.$store.commit('setActionTitle', 'Medical Service BD')
  },
}
```